Get certificate fingerprint of HTTPS server on React Native
I am developing an application with React Native. I entered fingerprint and pin values ​​statically into the application for SSL pinning. But now I need to pull them from the server. How can I do the same thing in React Native where I can pull the fingerprint in the terminal as below?
echo | openssl s_client -connect serverName.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | base64


Your shell command has several steps, which steps are you unable to implement in React Native and why?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I need to get the server's ssl fingerprint and pin values. I can get the fingerprint with this command and I want to get the same process in the application to use it in the API request.
